# How to extract json and randomize it in jmeter?

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

Below is the server response in a JSON format which I need to work on, In this JSON some of the objects I need to pass in the next request, which I am successfully able to do for the first occurrence, but the problem is coming on randomization in the below JSON

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "test_title",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "India",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

if I apply `$..book[0][?(@.title == 'Sword of Honour')].author` condition I am seeing successful output but when I use `$..book[1][?(@.title == 'Sword of Honour')].author` I get a blank O/P which I understand all because at `book[1]` level there is not title like that.

How do I randomize the data in every Iteration so that it picks different authors for the same title? we have to take multiple values from JSON and pass it in the next request.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract all the titles using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor):

   [image]

   It will give you the following variables:

   ```
   title_1=Sword of Honour
   title_2=test_title
   title_3=Sword of Honour
   title_4=India
   title_matchNr=4
   ```

   [image]
2. Then you can use [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) and [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) functions combination to refer the random book title where required:

   ```
   ${__V(title_${__Random(1,${title_matchNr},)},)}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri, this example will be good for one value pair but if i want two name value pair like title, price how do i randomize it making sure it is taking same price for the same title,, it should not take title from one group and price from another group